# How to Style Home Controller Title in xCode using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, controller, styles

Forgive my lack of proper terminology here:

When my app loads there is a thick grey bar at the top of the screen. It was not there before I added the navigation controller - which I need. I want to remove the HEAD or make it much thinner.

Is there anyway to style the title/head of the "Home" ViewController?

If not, what other options do I have whether programatic or other.

If this is in the Apple docs, I'd be happy to be shown where...
Can anyone please enlighten me... + thanks again SO!

Comment: For any newbies like myself: Here is what I found and it works: navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true

Comment: Even better: navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

Comment: If you are happy that you have answered your own question you can copy this into an answer and then tick that answer as correct - you wont get 'rep' for answering your own question but it saves it hanging around as 'unanswered' and may help others with the same problem.

Comment: Ali - Will do Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any newbies like myself: Here is what I found and it works:
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true